# Implementing Google CSE Results Code

Tags: search

I'm trying to implement the Google CSE Search Results code on a page that I created called search-results. When I implement the code using CKEditor (PHP mode) and save the page, the code does not show up when the page is rendered?

I was able to enter the Search box code no problem but I cannot seem to get the search results code to load on a page? I created a static html page and it works fine but will not work when I create the page in CKEditor. I also tried creating a block but this did not work?

How can I get the Google CSE Search results code snippet in a Drupal page? I'm not interested in using any of the Drupal modules for CSE as I don't like the way they render the results.

Comment: Here's a good example: https://www.drupal.org/node/1887016

Answer (score -1):

You should be using [Google Custom Search Engine](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_cse) Module instead of embedding the code. Using this module would give you better integration option.

Additional Info: Avoid using PHP Filter as its creates security risk.

Comment: I tried the Google Custom Search Engine Module but it does not create a results page the same way as the raw Google code. I wanted the WEB and IMAGE results tabs.

Comment: So, why won't the Search results code get loaded on the page when I have no issues loading the search box code?